# How to recover unbootable system?

Tags: 10.10, boot, freeze

I have just run the most recent set of recommended updates on a 10.10 system. The computer is now un-bootable.

It gets as far as the "Ubuntu..." splash and then does nothing. I cannot switch to a console. Booting from the 10.10 Live-CD is fine.

Seems like no point in doing a reinstall, as I'll probably end up at the same point. Downgrade the kernel or other software from the Live-CD??
Any recommendations?

---

This is a work computer, so I need to fix this ASAP. Is Ubuntu 10.10 not recommended for corporate environment. Should I be using another distro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a work machine then you should certainly consider sticking with the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Long Term Support) release which will get point releases and bug fixes. I wouldn't put my work machine on 10.10 unless working on fixing Ubuntu was my work.

For your unbootable problem, you can install or you can provide a dmesg log to a bug report so the problem can be prevented in future:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (likely you already fixed yours by now). The best that I could figure out is that if I pressed F1 while the system was stuck in the Ubuntu splash screen, I could get into the terminal. At least there I could recover all of my data. I ended up doing what Martin Owens suggested and put 10.04 LTS after transferring all of my data by flash drive! To do that you have to type

`mkdir flash`
`sudo fdisk -l`
`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 flash`

You'll have to enter your password for sudo privileges. Then your flash drive will be mounted in the folder "flash". Also your device might not be called /dev/sdb1, you'll be able to see this after doing the `sudo fdisk -l` (it should be the final one listed).

To eject the drive cd to the directory below "flash" and type

`sudo umount /dev/sdb1`

At least you can save your data this way. Sort of a pain, but it was all I could figure out!